# D3js highlight bar one by one continuously

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, bar-chart

Here is the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/51Lsj6ym/2/)

Below code is to create bar

```
      svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset, key)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
   .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return "blue";
   })

    //Tooltip
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style("fill","red");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this).style("fill","blue");
    })  ;
```

On mouseover bar gets red color, and on mouseout it gets back to blue color,

I want it to continuously get red color one by one means first bar red then second bar, then third, after moving ahead previous bar should restore its origin color, there will be only one red bar at a time. and it should be like when it reach to end, it should again start from beginning

Comment: `I want it to continuously get red color one by one` confused by this sentence, can you give more description?

Comment: I have elaborated.

Comment: Its D3.js bar chart, I have given sample jsfiddle

Comment: what do you mean by after moving ahead previous color should restore its origin color..currently also there is one bar which is red on mouse hover so whats the difference, with what is there and what you want to achieve.

Comment: What you want is 'chained transitions': http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997

Answer (score 3):

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/DavidGuan/f07wozud/4/

Code I added:

```
function reRenderColor() {
  svg.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i){ return i* 500 })
      .duration(200)
      .style('fill', 'red')
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i){ return i* 500 + 400 })
      .duration(200)
      .style('fill', 'blue')
}  

reRenderColor();
setInterval(reRenderColor, svg.selectAll("rect").size() * 500 + 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave `.attr("id", function(d,i){return "rect"+i;});` to your rect elements in order to select them. Then, I used a recursive setTimout function to solve this with d3 transition property.

```
 var z = 0;
  var timeoutFunc = function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(z < 20){
      d3.select("#rect"+ z).transition().duration(350).attr("fill","red")
                           .transition().delay(550).attr("fill","blue");       
      z++;
      timeoutFunc();
    }else if(z == 20){
        z = 0;
      timeoutFunc();
    }    
  },500);
  };
```

Here's an updated fiddle.

Note that durations could be changed for a better color visualization but this will give you an idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/51Lsj6ym/5/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want

```
//Tooltip
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll("rect").style("fill","blue");
    d3.select(this).style("fill","red");
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
})  ;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqyx8czr/)