# continuous loop between first and last element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to run continuous loop between first and last element

Below is sample code

```
 d3.selectAll('.radarArea').each(function (d, i) {
                   // add style to this element
                   // remove style to other than this element.
                   // if it is last then again start from first element 
                });
```

Thanks

Comment: `i` represents `index` right ? And `d3.selectAll('.radarArea')` will give you the length!

Comment: Then what is the question ?

Comment: Question is if it reached to last element how to re-initiate this iteration.

Comment: I need to implement this here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735709/d3js-highlight-bar-one-by-one-continuously]

Comment: `function doItAlways() {
  d3.selectAll('.radarArea').each(function(d, i) {
    if (LAST_ITEM) {
      doItAlways();
    }
  });
}`

Comment: I suspect there is something which does not need explicitly defining other function, and I am looking that, putting this inside a function is very simple. and it will also may hang the browser..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109627/discussion-between-md-parvez-alam-and-rayon-dabre).

Answer (score 1):

There is API from d3 aim at that:https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#active

but it need v4, which not finish totally yet, so:

```
var radarAreas = d3.selectAll('.radarArea')
setInterval(function() {
  radarAreas.each(function (d, i) {
      // add style to this element
      // remove style to other than this element.
      // if it is last then again start from first element 
   });
}, time)
```